# When using typealias, I get the compiler error "use of undeclared type"

Tags: swift, type-alias

I'm new to Swift and is trying to learn the concept of Type Aliases. I tried to compile the code below:

```
var x = 23
typealias y = x // compiler output: use of undeclared type x
print(y)
```

However, the compiler tell me "use of undeclared type x".

I'm very confused by why this is happening. I thought Swift can implicitly infer to the variable type. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You ask the compiler to assign x, which is an variable with value Int(23) as an associated type y. That is impossible ... Please check, that x doesn't represent a type, but the value.

Comment: As @user3441734 said, `x` is a variable, not a type. [Type aliases](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID327) need a type to alias, e.g. `typealias y = Int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use typealias to make it easier for you declaring more complex types for example:

```
typealias RGBA = (red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)

let redColor: RGBA = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

redColor.red    // 1
redColor.green  // 0
redColor.blue   // 0
redColor.alpha  // 1

typealias CMYK =  (cyan: CGFloat, magenta: CGFloat, yellow: CGFloat, black: CGFloat)

let cyanColor: CMYK = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

cyanColor.cyan     // 1
cyanColor.magenta  // 0
cyanColor.yellow   // 0
cyanColor.black    // 0
```